# How to use a provided keystore to sign a jar file

Tags: java, security, applet, signing

My client gave me a keystore for the purpose of signing a Java applet jar file. I exported a .cer file from it and then imported it into cacerts but I keep getting "Certificate chain not found" error. It also says "alias must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponsing public key certificate chain."

I tried Gaston's suggestion below, it went as follows:

```
jarsigner -keystore "D:\My Documents\keystore\MyKeyStore.jks" -storepass mypass -signedjar my_signed_jar.jar" unsigned.jar myalias

Warning:
The signer's certificate chain is not validated.
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire situation is invalid.

1. You're supposed to sign JAR files with your own private key, not somebody else's.
2. Your client has committed a **MAJOR** security breach by giving away his private key.
3. The problem you mention about the signer's certificate chain being not validated is entirely the client's problem. He provided the certificate: its validity is entirely up to him.

Not your problem, but not a real problem at all as the entire situation is invalid. You should be signing your own code with your own certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sign a jar from a keystore, you should run the following in the command-line:

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jarsigner -keystore YOUR_KEY_STORE.ks -storepass KS_PASS YOUR_JAR KS_ALIAS

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried that and this was the result:

jarsigner -keystore "D:\My Documents\keystore\ProvidedKeyStore.jks" -storepass mypass -signedjar my_signed_jar.jar" unsigned.jar myalias

Warning:
The signer's certificate chain is not validated.

Comment: If you use JDK 7, try now with JDK 6 version (try with 32 and 64 bits version too).

Answer (score 0):

> I exported a .cer file from it and then imported it into cacerts but I
>   keep getting "Certificate chain not found" error.

Of course, the chain won't be found :) You **shouldn't export** it because to sign a jar but you have to use the original keystore key - the key the cert was generated of...

If you have all privileges as passwords etc you should use the original keystore key the client gave you to sign the jar. Next you have to use [jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/jarsigner.html) common commands something like

```
jarsigner -keystore C:\working\mystore -storepass myspass
      -keypass dukekeypasswd MyJarFile.jar duke
```

P.S>

Please report if that helps